# What port needs to be open for Debian to get updates?

Tags: security, port, debian-lenny

I was considering deploying my web application on a Debian virtual machine. However, I want to lock it down as tight as possible (i.e. traffic in/out). I was wondering which, if any, port I needed to leave open to allow for updates.

Comment: Also important: A firewall keeps track of tcp connections. So it recognizes reply packets from a request sent with tcp packets. https://superuser.com/questions/923937/how-does-my-computers-firewall-work-like-inbound-rule-outbound-rule-reply

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All a default Debian install needs for updates is DNS traffic for name->address lookups (though you can remove this requirement by having the relevant names in your /etc/hosts file) and HTTP traffic to the servers listed in your `sources.list` file.

Comment: Thanks! I'll rephrase that for anyone (like me) that might not have caught all of that on the first read . . . Two ports are necessary for a default Debian install to get updates: the DNS lookup port (typically 53) and the HTTP port (typically 80). However, you can also disable the DNS lookup port if you put any needed domain names with their IP addresses in your /etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 4):

Just about all apt-get sources use http, check your /etc/apt/sources.list.

You can also check the ruleset of iptables or ipchains to see if there is a rule that affects apt-gets usage.